# How do I get access to the PS4 platform tools for Unity?

Tags: unity, publishing, playstation4

I know that you can go to the "Xbox ID" program to get all the resources you need for the Xbox platform (developer forums, Unity SDK, etc.). but there is not really information about how to get the PlayStation tools.

...Well other than the contact sales button in Unity which links to Unity and not Sony (oddly enough).

So where does someone who hopes to put their games onto one of the Sony platforms (PS4, Vita, PS3, etc) go to get the build tools (and other things) they need? Do Sony contact you about it if they're interested or is it really only for developers who are considered above Indy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching "PS4 tools for Unity" turns up [this site](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/develop/):

> How can my team get Unity for PlayStation®4?
>
> Start by [registering with Sony](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/develop/). Once registered, developers can
>   download Unity for PlayStation®4, get creating and self-publish. It’s
>   that simple.

You can also register to be a PlayStation(R) Partner [at this link:](https://partners.playstation.com/apex/PO_AccountAppliPTR?lang=en)

> Before applying, you will need the following:
>
> - If you are based in the US, a corporate entity and an Employer Tax ID
>     Number (see www.irs.gov)
> - A Static IP address (required for access to
>     SIE developer and publisher websites)
> - A non-public domain email
>     address (Gmail, Hotmail, etc. are not acceptable)
>
> For any questions,
>   please contact:
>
> SIEA (Americas): Selfpublish@playstation.sony.com
>
> SIEE (Europe, Middle East, Africa, India, Australia, New Zealand):
>   PS_Partners_Registration@scee.net

Comment: "Searching "PS4 tools for Unity"" now also returns to this question on the first page of google :D

Comment: Haha, Google indexing is FAST!